# R map_dbl() to extract character

Tags: r

This is a beginner silly R question:

```
df <- tribble(  
  ~x,
  list(a = 1, b = 2),
  list(a = 2, c = 4)
  )

df %>%
  mutate(
    a = map_dbl(x, "a"),   
    b = map_dbl(x, "b", .null = NA_real_)
  )
```

Question 1: in help or RSiteSearch(), I do not fund anything for .null.  Where do I learn the appropriate timing to use it?

Question 2: in help I always see this: map_dbl(.x, .f, ...).  What is the '...' and what is/are arguments considered acceptable for a function?

Comment: I don't see anything with `.null` in `?map_dbl` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything with `.null` in documentation of `?map_dbl`.

`...` is used as additional arguments that can be passed to `.f` function. This is similar to what is present in lot of other functions like `?aggregate`. To understand that consider this example.

```
df <- structure(list(a = 1:2, b = list(c(1, 2), c(2, NA))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df

#      a b        
#  <int> <list>   
#1     1 <dbl [2]>
#2     2 <dbl [2]>

df$b
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1]  2 NA
```

Notice that there is `NA` value in second element of `b`.

To take mean of each list in `b` using `map_dbl` we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(c = map_dbl(b, mean))

#     a b             c
#  <int> <list>    <dbl>
#1     1 <dbl [2]>   1.5
#2     2 <dbl [2]>  NA
```

To ignore `NA` values we need to pass `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean` which can use `...` part.

```
df %>% mutate(c = map_dbl(b, mean, na.rm = TRUE))

#     a b             c
#  <int> <list>    <dbl>
#1     1 <dbl [2]>   1.5
#2     2 <dbl [2]>   2
```

You can ignore the `...` part if you use an anonymous function or a formula style syntax.

```
df %>% mutate(c = map_dbl(b, ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply`

```
 df %>%
     mutate(c = sapply(b, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
 # A tibble: 2 x 3
 #     a b             c
 #  <int> <list>    <dbl>
 #1     1 <dbl [2]>   1.5
 #2     2 <dbl [2]>   2
```